# JavaScript checkbox validation in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I have designed a table  below using HTML. I have validated for only one row, but for the 2nd row it was not validated. Below UI have given submit that validates entire table.
Condition is that at least one checkbox should be selected from each row.

[image]

Comment: where is the image??

Comment: please upload the images

Comment: SORRY I NEED 10 REPUTATION TO POST IMAGES, but table consists of 5 rows ,6 columns

Comment: Do you have some code to show?

Comment: function validate(form)
  { 
   var checkboxs=document.getElementsByName("m1");
   var okay=false;
   for(var i=0,l=checkboxs.length;i<l;i++)
   {
    if(checkboxs[i].checked)
    {
     okay=true;
     break;
    }
   }
   if(okay)
    return true;
   else
   {
    alert("Please select atleast one item for male patients");
    return false;
   }
  }
 </script>

Comment: its fiddile link please check it  https://jsfiddle.net/v8mghww9/

Comment: Image link http://postimg.org/image/wjfg9asd9/

Answer (score 1):

Using pure js: https://jsfiddle.net/v8mghww9/1/

```
function validate(form)
{ 
    var rows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');
    var isTableValid = true;
    for(var i=0;i<rows.length;i++) {
        var checkboxs=rows[i].getElementsByTagName("input");                                           
        var okay=false;
        for(var j=0;j<checkboxs.length;j++)
        {
            console.log('here' + checkboxs[j].checked);
            if(checkboxs[j].checked)
            {
                okay=true;
                break;
            }
        }
        if(!okay && checkboxs.length > 0) {
            isTableValid = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    if(isTableValid)
            return true;
        else
        {
            alert("Please select atleast one item for male patients");
            return false;
        }

}
```

Comment: Thank you but i need to make it in JS only

Comment: sorry! jquery tag was there in question.. let me update

Comment: plz check  my image link http://postimg.org/image/wjfg9asd9/ and fiddle link  jsfiddle.net/v8mghww9

Answer (score 1):

Your code was fine but you weren't writing the jsfiddle the right way, this is a live snippet showing that your code works fine:

```js
function validate(form) {
  var checkboxs = document.getElementsByName("m1");
  var okay = false;
  for (var i = 0, l = checkboxs.length; i < l; i++) {
    if (checkboxs[i].checked) {
      okay = true;
      break;
    }
  }
  if (okay) return true;
  else {
    alert("Please select atleast one item for male patients");
    return false;
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  padding: 0.5em;
  line-height: 1.5em;
}
#color {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
.adjust {
  text-align: left;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  margin-left: 47%;
}
```

```html
<table border="1" width="100%">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="3">OAB Patient Types</th>
    <th colspan="6" id="color">Therapy of First Choice</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="4" id="color">Muscarinic Antagonists</th>
    <th style="background-color:lightblue">Beta-3 Adrenergic Agonist</th>
    <th style="background-color:lightblue">Other Therapies</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th>Detrol LA
      <br>(tolterodine)</th>
    <th>Enablex
      <br>(darifencian)</th>
    <th>Toviaz
      <br>(festoridine)</th>
    <th>VESIcare
      <br>(solifencian)</th>
    <th>Myrbetriq
      <br>(merabergan)</th>
    <th>Other</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" id="color" class="adjust">General Patient Types</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Male Patients</td>//
    <form name=form1>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=m1>
      </td>//</form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Female Patients</td>
    <form name=form2>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox" name=f1>
      </td>
      <!-- <td><input type="submit" value="submit"></td> -->
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="7" id="color" class="adjust">Line of Therapy</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>First-line (newly daignosed OAB patients on their first course of therapy)</td>
    <form>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Second-line</td>
    <form>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Third-line</td>
    <form>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
      <td>
        <input type="checkbox">
      </td>
    </form>
  </tr>
</table>
<br>
<br>
<center>
  <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick='return validate()'>
</center>
```

**Note:**

The button `Submit` should be of type `button` and not `submit`.

- First thing because it's not inside any form to be submitted
- Second thing is that you have many forms in your page (which is strange here), so you may have a conflict in submitting which form of them wityh this submit button?

Comment: @SonuSandeep you are welcome, please accept the answer if it helps you.

Answer (score 1):

give the same name on all the checkboxes of each row and then give it a class to all which you want to validate.

```
function validate() {

    var flag = true;
    var array = [];
    $(".js-validate-required-radio").each(function () {
        array.push($(this).prop('name'));
    });
    var uniqueNames = $.unique(array);
    for (var i = 0; i < uniqueNames.length; i++) {
        if ($('input:checkbox[name=' + uniqueNames[i] + ']:checked').val() == undefined) {
             if (flag) {
                flag = false;
            }
        }
    }
    if(!flag){
    alert('select atleast one radio on each row');    
    }
    else{
            alert('yeee');    
    }
    return flag;
}
```

[here is fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/v8mghww9/2/)